# Greatest common divisor of coefficients

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers, gcd-and-lcm, discriminant

I recently stumbled across the following statement. Let $d \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0, 1\}$ be square free,

$$
D = 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-} 4d & d \equiv 2, 3 \text{ mod } 4
\\[4pt]
     \,\,\,\,\,d & d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4
\end{cases}
$$
If $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $D = b^2 - 4ac$ then gcd($a, b, c$) $= 1$. Where does this come from? The gcd equality is written like something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k = \gcd(a,b,c)$, with $a=kA, b=kB, c=kC$. Then
$$D = b^2-4ac = k^2(B^2-4AC).$$
Since $d$ is square free, it follows that $k=1$ if $D = d$.

For the case $D = 4d$, it is possible that $k=2$, so that $d = B^2-4AC$. But then we have $d \equiv B^2 \pmod4$, which is impossible since $d \equiv 2 \text{ or } 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Ok, this was indeed easy. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $d \mid D$? Then what about the case $D = 4d$? Why is $k \neq 2$?

Comment: @Quadrat Oh, good point. I'm confused about that, since it doesn't seem to follow. (See my edits). Perhaps there is additional context?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up and the conditions were switched and your proof is correct. I fixed the question.

Comment: In the case $D = 4d, k = 2$ it follows $d = B^2 - 4ac$ and $d \equiv 2, 3 \text{ mod } 4$. This is a contradiction, since $2, 3$ are no quadratic residues mod 4.

Comment: @Quadrat Yes, that makes sense now; I've edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the typo and thanks again!